# D3 - multi line chart, line position offset

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-scatter-mt-fyhu6y?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts)

I have a D3 chart where I'm trying to plot a number of lines from one data input

I have the line and cicles working but they aren't positioned correctly, they seem to be offset to the left and up from where they should be.

I think it must be how I'm setting the domain but I can't work out how to do it.

```
this.x.domain(data[0].values.map((d:any) => d.date));

this.y.domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.value)])
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have this problem, but I guess you should be able to find out since you wrote it (maybe it has to do with starting at 0 instead of 1)

But changing `that.x(d.date) + 0.5 * that.x.bandwidth()` to `that.x(d.date) + 1.5 * that.x.bandwidth()` do the trick.

For the height I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out - I was attaching the line group to the svg and not to the group that had already been positioned on the svg.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-scatter-mt-fyhu6y?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts